# When the browser page is too narrow, the right-most section hides at the bottom of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

So, at first I thought the right sidebar was just missing... and then I scrolled down and discovered that it wasn't missing at all... it was hiding!

On most pages, this is just the right sidebar, which isn't a huge loss (it's annoying but the main page content is still there)... but on the "edit user profile & settings page, the content of the actual list item is gone:

With a narrow browser window - when you scroll down, the content is there but if you're unaware of this issue, it can seem like the page is broken:

[image: Narrow browser window]

Wider browser window:

[image: Wide browser window]

My understanding is that [the plan is to make the screen size fully responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306814/284336), which will be great but it doesn't seem to be quite working yet.

---

I'm using FF 58.0.2 for Mac, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minor bug is fixed. Responsive is being turned on (today) for all Team's users. This will momentarily make things worse since some pages that have not been made responsive will be (it's ugly). We have a fix to turn off responsive for the pages we haven't gotten to (a lot). And, then we will actually make those responsive, but that will take time. So complicated.